# StyleSheet only Updates When Making Changes to Functions.Php in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

```
<?php
// styles of the child theme
function uni_bauhaus_theme_child_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), '4.5.0' );

    wp_register_style( 'ball-clip-rotate-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ball-clip-rotate.css', '0.1.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'ball-clip-rotate-style');

    wp_register_style( 'bxslider-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bxslider.css', '4.2.3' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bxslider-style');

    wp_register_style( 'fancybox-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/fancybox.css', '2.1.5' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fancybox-style');

    wp_register_style( 'jscrollpane-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/jscrollpane.css', '2.1.5' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jscrollpane-style');

    wp_register_style( 'unitheme-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('ball-clip-rotate-style', 'bxslider-style',
    'fancybox-style', 'jscrollpane-style'), '1.3.1', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'unitheme-styles' );

    wp_register_style( 'unitheme-adaptive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/adaptive.css', array('unitheme-styles'), false, 'screen' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'unitheme-adaptive' );

    wp_register_style( 'unichild-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('unitheme-adaptive'), false,  'screen' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'unichild-styles' );

}
```

This is the enque function in the child theme. Updates to the css are only loaded if I make a change to the functions.php file and reupload it. Otherwise the site loads the old css. Turned off all cacheing.

Comment: how did you knew that it's load the old css ? make sure that your browser does not caching your css files

Answer (score 0):

If you enqueue your files with *auto-versioning*, you'll never have to worry about cache issues again:

```
$cssPath = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css';

wp_enqueue_style(
    'unichild-styles',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array(),
    filemtime($cssPath)
);
```

This simply adds the time the css file was last saved as the version "number" ensuring zero cache problems locally or remotely :)